# Who is the main leader of SPQR?

Tags: rome-total-war

In Rome Total War what major military leader is the faction dominance for SPQR? If you assassinate all SPQR members can they crumble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you assassinate all SPQR members can they crumble?

Yes.

However, this is an very tall order when talking about the SPQR, as they usually have only 2 stacks of troops (one in Rome and the free-roaming stack outside the city). A high concentration of troops and generals makes a successful assassination mission very unlikely.

But yes, it's possible.

Edit: Of course, this can only be done after the civil war starts.

Comment: I would like to see the evidence.

Comment: @youngguilo Evidence of what?

Comment: Wheres the evidence that proves you can do this. Post a screen shot.

Comment: Any faction is eliminated when all the family members are killed. The only faction this does not apply to are the Rebels - as they are actually many different factions, and they operate under a different set of rules.